Standard Contact Phone field not visible in flow
I am attempting to create a Contact record using a record-triggered flow. However, the standard 'Phone' field is not available among the fields that can be populated. I have verified the field-level security (FLS), and it is set to visible for all profiles.



Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to include more details.  Are you using the Create Records action?  Please post a screenshot with more of the Create Records screen visible.  Are other contact fields available?  Please [edit] your post.
